# Regex for asp.net default password field

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, aspnetdb

Can anyone help me with a regex for the standard password field for the ASPNETDB.MDF password field?

Its 7 characters 1 has to be a special character.

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try here:

http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password